# percentage height with display flex breaks layout

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I want to implement this layout:

[image: layout]

- where the body takes full view height,
- it has a fixed height app-bar
- and a main section that takes the rest available space using flex-grow: 1.

Inside the main section,

- there is a card that I want to have 80% of the height of the main section
- and the card to be scrollable (to have content that exceeds its height)

The problem appears to be when I set the *card height* to *80%*. There is no problem when i set it to fixed *800px*

```css
body {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

body main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* HERE IS THE ISSUE */
/* (uncomment height: 80%) */
body main #main-card {
  height: 400px;
/* height: 80%; */  
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 400px;  
}

body main #main-card #main-card-content {
  background: #bf8040;
  height: 150vh;
}

body header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div id="main-card">
      <div id="main-card-content"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

I can fix it by setting main height to be 100vh minus the height of the header, but I would like to keep the flex-grow property

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexkougianos/pen/poKRqzw?editors=0100) that replicates the problem

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using percentage heights, you need a [defined height on the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276).

Otherwise, the percentage you set has no reference ("80% of what?").

The parent does have `flex-grow: 1`, but that isn't a defined height, it's just a command to consume available space.

Since the app-bar has a fixed height (50px), the solution is actually simple:

Replace `flex-grow: 1` with `height: calc(100vh - 50px)`.

The `height: 80%` on `#main-card` will work now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same, but setting:

```
height: calc(80vh - 50px);
```

Would give you largely the same output. Not exactly the same though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add on your .main class `height: calc(100% - 50px);`